# How can you run only one class in a package and among several runnable classes?

Tags: java, class, jframe

I have few classes include Java JFrame forms and java class.
I want to do something so that the Java class runs only and the forms run by that class. (I have coded the last item).
What can I do now?

Comment: it would be better to show sample code of what you did and what is the current result your get and what the expected result you want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.